# Is Google Dictionary API now comes under Google custom engine?

Tags: java, google-api, jsoup

I asked the same question on google developer forum, looking for clear direction for the same.

I am working on a project to get meaning of English word. And Google search engine provides result comprehensively. I would like to have those results (meaning of words, it's synonym, audio source from gstatic, usage graph since 1800, etc...) as input to my program for further processing. Is Custom search engine has exposed API or Google have explicit API for this? Earlier i thought of screen scraping, but it would be much easier if Google provide API for this as well.

Thanks in Anticipation.

Comment: You can use https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/, I created it by scraping google search.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Wikitionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiktionary)

> Wiktionary (whose name is a blend of the words wiki and dictionary) is
>   a multilingual, web-based project to create a free content dictionary
>   of all words in all languages. It is available in 172 languages and in
>   Simple English. Like its sister project Wikipedia, Wiktionary is run
>   by the Wikimedia Foundation, and is written collaboratively by
>   volunteers, dubbed "Wiktionarians". Its wiki software, MediaWiki,
>   allows almost anyone with access to the website to create and edit
>   entries.

You can access their data using the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tutorial), no need to scrape google search results.