# Which API allows access to Google's Dictionary information?

Tags: dictionary, google-api

I know that Google Dictionary was [discontinued in 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Dictionary), but the dictionary information and definitions are still available through google search results:

[image]

Does anyone know whether this information can be accessed through the Custom Search API or the Translate API?

I found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630756/is-google-dictionary-api-now-comes-under-google-custom-engine) (but sadly without a satisfying answer).

Comment: Google Dictionary's content is licenced from Oxford Dictionaries' [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/). Their API can be accessed from [here](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I also needed Google Dictionary API for my project, it was not present so I decided to create one.

I  scrapped the WebPage for the url `https://www.google.com/#q=define+term` where `term` is any word you want to get meaning of, and created the API, you can find it here [Google Dictionary API](https://dictionaryapi.dev/).

## How to use

The basic syntax of a URL request to the API is shown below:

https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/<--language_code-->/<--word-->

As an example, to get definition of English word hello, you can send request to:

https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello

The API also provides other meanings of the word, example sentences, and synonyms, if any.

If you want me to include any other details, please comment and I will happily extend the API to cover your needs.

In case you wish to see the code, it is on [github](https://github.com/meetDeveloper/googleDictionayAPI).

Comment: Nice job! However it doesn't give back the full results that google dictionary provides. Would be cool if you could extend so that it allows access to the full power google dict has to offer.

Comment: @martin-martin I am adding synonyms and sound shortly.  People on this site is downvoting my answers such as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50319736/5473170, just because I am scrapping google. Maybe they will even downvote this one.

Comment: sorry about that. I find your effort great and useful! it's a pity that google is not providing an API for their dictionary, I think it's good that you are working on making this information easier available! don't get demotivated :) I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @martin-martin Added synonyms support, you can open issue at https://github.com/meetDeveloper/googleDictionayAPI, if you want to request any new feature, what else can I add??

Comment: Also now the API gives 404 status code for words which does not have meaning on google dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Google Dictionary's content is licenced from Oxford Dictionaries' [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/). Their API can be accessed from [here](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/).

Note their free access platform ("prototype") has a number of limitations:

> 1000 requests per month
> Limited data access
> Limited request rate

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look promising from the API Explorer

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/dictionary/

Comment: It is gone. Here are some alternatives: https://medium.com/@martin.breuss/finding-a-useful-dictionary-api-52084a01503d